# KeyError: 'Filter' (receiving specific data from dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas, dataset, data-science, src

So, the order is "Ask the user to enter the name of the object for which he/she wants to receive data and the names of the filters,
data in which you need (it is possible to introduce several filters)."

this is my data:

| Object | HJD 24... | Filter | Magnitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SU_Hor | 55896.30476 | B | 14.877 |
| SU_Hor | 55896.27438 | Ic | 13.885 |
| SU_Hor | 55896.27349 | B | 14.809 |
| SU_Hor | 55896.27397 | V | 14.434 |
| SU_Hor | 55896.40882 | Ic | 14.033 |
| SU_Hor | 55896.40829 | V | 14.540 |
| SU_Hor | 55896.40770 | B | 14.941 |
| SU_Hor | 55896.34973 | Ic | 13.958 |
| SU_Hor | 55896.34943 | V | 14.494 |
| SU_Hor | 55896.34906 | B | 14.861 |
| SU_Hor | 55896.30542 | Ic | 13.912 |
| SU_Hor | 55896.30512 | v | 14.440 |
| SU_Hor | 55897.38547 | V | 14.536 |
| SU_Hor | 55897.28281 | B | 14.882 |
| SU_Hor | 55897.28317 | V | 14.428 |
| SU_Hor | 55897.28347 | Ic | 13.927 |
| RZ_Lyr | 27359.3030 | V | 10.630 |
| RZ_Lyr | 27684.4510 | V | 10.610 |
| RZ_Lyr | 27685.4780 | V | 10.580 |
| RZ_Lyr | 27701.3150 | V | 10.700 |
| RZ Lyr | 27934.4560 | V | 10.660 |
| RZ Lyr | 27955.4100 | V | 10.570 |
| rzlyr | 30604.2000 | V | 11.030 |
| RZ_Lyr | 55314.5695 | B | 12.047 |
| RZ_Lyr | 55314.5724 | B | 12.036 |
| RZ_Lyr | 55314.5900 | B | 12.042 |
| RZ_Lyr | 55314.6105 | B | 12.045 |
| RZ_Lyr | 55314.6163 | B | 12.027 |
| RZ_Lyr | 55342.3509 | B | 12.057 |
| RZLyr | 55342.3557 | B | 12.058 |
| RZ_Lyr | 55342.3606 | B | 12.052 |
| RZ_Lyr | 55342.3654 | B | 12.058 |

here is my code:

```
def searchByFilter():
    filter = input('Enter filter to show data \n')
    df = pd.read_csv('Python_2ndLab.csv')
    print(df.loc[df['Filter'] == filter, :])


print('Enter 1 to search by object name')
print('Enter 2 to search by filter')

src = (input('Enter here: '))

if src == '1':
    searchByObject()
elif src == '2':
    searchByFilter()
else:
    print('Sorry, invalid input')
```

So in the output, I enter "2" to search by the filter, then the output ask to enter the filter name then I enter "B" but instead of the data from the B filter, I receive the error.

```
Name: Filter, dtype: object
Enter 1 to search by object name
Enter 2 to search by filter
Enter here: 2
Enter filter to show data 
B
```

this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3803, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 165, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5745, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5753, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Filter'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Acer\PycharmProjects\2nd Lab\main.py", line 78, in <module>
    searchByFilter()
  File "C:\Users\Acer\PycharmProjects\2nd Lab\main.py", line 64, in searchByFilter
    print(df.loc[df['Filter'] == filter, :])
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3805, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3805, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'Filter'
```

Could anyone help me to debug it? I really have no idea where is the error.

Comment: Do not use built-in functions as a variable.

Comment: so what should I do instead? @Bushmaster

Comment: it looks like there is no column named `Filter` in the df. Check column names. Also you should use something like this (to avoid using built-in function): `filter_x = input('Enter filter to show data \n')` instead of  `filter = input('Enter filter to show data \n')`

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code below and everything worked for me

```
import pandas as pd

def searchByFilter():
    filter = input('Enter filter to show data \n')
    df = pd.DataFrame({"Dummy":[1,2,3,4,5],
                       "Filter":["A","B","C","D","E"]})
    print(df.loc[df['Filter'] == filter,:])


print('Enter 1 to search by object name')
print('Enter 2 to search by filter')

src = (input('Enter here: '))

if src == '1':
    None
elif src == '2':
    searchByFilter()
else:
    print('Sorry, invalid input')

-----------------------------------

Enter 1 to search by object name
Enter 2 to search by filter
Enter here: 2
Enter filter to show data 
B
   Dummy Filter
1      2      B
```

The key error suggests that your 'Python_2ndLab.csv' file headers might not be formatted exactly as expected.  Check the file again and make sure there aren't any leading or trailing spaces that could cause this.  Opening the CSV in a text editor instead of excel makes these easier to spot.

Comment: I also can run your code but can't when I'm using my file. I already checked the file too and found unexpected spaces, then I deleted all of the spaces but still got the same error. Keyerror:'Filter' do you have any suggestion?

Comment: It's got to be an issue still with the input CSV.  I'd add `print(df)` and `print(df.columns)` between the import and the lookup just to inspect the data frame manually.